# use local variables in mysql IF statement

Tags: mysql, declaration

I modified the statements as below, but still errors at the line with the DECLARE statement.

BEGIN
DECLARE searchresult int(11);
SET searchresult=(Select count(*) from wbsimsynuqsql where SimBase='a cappella');
IF searchresult >0 THEN
 Select * from simsyn1sql where BaseID = (Select Distinct BaseID from wbsimsynuqsql where SimBase='a cappella')
ELSE
   Select * from simsyn1sql where BaseID = (Select Distinct BaseID from wbsimsynuqsql where SimSyn='a cappella')

END IF;
END

I am using the expression below in PHPMYADMIN with the intent to use it later in a PHP/MySQL application.  It gives an error relating to the DECLARE statement in line 1.

I've looked at example declarations in MySQL and I don't see an error, but I'm doing something wrong and would appreciate a correction/suggestion.

```
DECLARE searchresult int(11);
SET searchresult=(Select count(*) from wbsimsynuqsql where SimBase='a cappella');
IF searchresult >0
 {Select * from simsyn1sql where BaseID = (Select Distinct BaseID from wbsimsynuqsql where SimBase='a cappella')}
[ ELSE
   {Select * from simsyn1sql where BaseID = (Select Distinct BaseID from wbsimsynuqsql where SimSyn='a cappella')} ]

END IF;
```

Comment: There are no `{` and `[` brackets in `mysql`. Why did you put them?

Comment: @Shaharyar Maybe for good luck or out of wishful thinking. Why do they write documentation when nobody reads it?

Comment: @tadman I took that sarcasm as a learning curve and found out the usage of `{` in mysqlm but still couldn't find the `[`. Would you like to share your knowledge?

Comment: I mean that a lot of people here post "Help my code isn't working questions" when the code bears almost no resemblance to what's allowed in the language. Reading the documentation is essential, skimming a tutorial is not enough to understand something. I'm not sure where in the documentation the `[ ELSE` notation shows up, so I'm presuming this is just wishful thinking on the part of the person asking the question.

Comment: you need BEGIN and END inside a procedure or a function.

Answer (score 3):

**DECLARE** is permitted only inside a **BEGIN ... END** compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.
like inside a CREATE PROCEDURE you can use DECLARE

Your **IF** statement is missing a **THEN**

and remove the square brackets ([]) and the curly braces ({})

If your subquery returns more than one BaseID you might have to use `IN` instead of `=`

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50c0b8/1)